# counting rows while displaying the data in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two queries

```
select TC,li,it as ee from results 
where li = "not_applicable" and cpirt = "uu_X1"
```

The above query will output 10 results,
but If I put count in the same query, there is only one results.

```
select TC,li,it,COUNT(TC) as ee from results 
where li = "not_applicable" and cpirt = "uu_X1"
```

How can I make the second query output the counts for every `TC` using MYSQL

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY TC`.

I would do:

```
select TC,COUNT(TC) as ee from results 
where results.li = "not_applicable" and results.cpirt = "uu_X1"
GROUP BY TC
```